# MPlab Load two 16-bit values into data memory in big-endian format, and then perform a long addition

Tags: mplab

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4oXi.jpg)
Hi I would like some help on question 2 on what code I need in order to work out question 2
Load two 16-bit values into data memory in big-endian format, and then perform a long
addition.
I am a beginner and need some help
using pic18f45k50